# FragmentPagerAdapter setPrimaryItem called multiple times

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

Structure:
CoordinatorLayout -> AppBarLayout + ViewPager

Scroll RecyclerView or other touch gestures throw setPrimaryItem in ViewPager. Called from ViewPager.onMeasure. Its normal behavior?

(support libs 25.1.0)

Trace:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's expected.  I've noticed `ViewPager` calling the adapter methods redundantly too, and I assume Google has written the code this way to handle various corner cases.  You should write your adapter code to work correctly even if your methods are called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` calls `setPrimaryItem()` in it's populate method.

[ViewPager.populate()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#690)

The populate method in turn is called in a couple of cases, but the really important one (at least for figuring out these multiple calls) is the onMeasure() invocation.

[ViewPager.onMeasure()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#834)

Look at like 851.  Anything that causes the view hierarchy to remeasure is going to lead to your Adapter getting it's primary item calls set again.